# Create trigger after update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня в таблице есть `ID`, и `tr_code`,

```
ID         tr_code
15         587-20140125-79-15
255        655-20140525-65-255
4587       611-20160815-72-4587
...............................
35681      715-20170125-45-35681
```

мне нужен создать тригер чтобы проверял если `ID` не совпадает с последним цифрами после - на tr_code, исправил:
*НАПРИМЕР*

```
ID         tr_code
*381*        587-20140125-79-*384*
```

Он бы исправил на так

```
ID         tr_code
*381*        587-20140125-79-*381*
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы меняете вводимые пользовательские данные до завершения транзакции - в этом случае лучше использовать время BEFORE. `test` - название вашей таблицы:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_checkCode` BEFORE UPDATE ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE code integer default 0;
DECLARE newCode varchar(250) default '';

SET code = RIGHT(NEW.`tr_code`, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX( REVERSE(NEW.`tr_code`), '-', 1 ) ) );
if(NEW.ID != code) THEN
SET newCode = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX( new.tr_code,  '-', (LENGTH( new.tr_code ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( new.tr_code,  '-',  '' ) ) ) ), '-' , NEW.ID
  ) ;
SET NEW.`tr_code` = newCode;
END IF;
END
```

Здесь я использовал:

- строковые функции https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html
- третьим аргументом SUBSTRING_INDEX рассчитал число вхождений - для удобства рекомендуется вынести это в отдельную функцию - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#c8024

P.S. Для такой модерации, моё мнение, стоит рассмотреть возможность выноса кода на уровень ввода, а не записи в БД.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: тепер тот update нужен создать с помашю procedure